# Stable bubbles in a vacuum

Tags: pressure, material-science, vacuum, surface-tension, solar-wind

I want to make space bubbles that hold some gaseous stuff - at very low pressure - for a long time and through nothing but surface tension.

I can't use soap water as the water will evaporate quickly.

A rubber balloon will work, but I'm looking for a much lighter membrane that is also transparent to solar wind (I'm musing about the famous sun shade idea and whether some kind of bubble would be suitable; there are other problems, but this question is about the bubble part).

Comment: How can your bubbles hold gas and also allow solar wind, which is mostly hydrogen + helium, to pass through? Why do they need to be "transparent" to the solar wind?

Comment: I've not decided on what it would hold, and if it's a real gas at all (could also be vapor or dust). If the membrane is not transparent to solar wind, there's the question on what effect the pressure, heat and acceleration would have and how it could be handled. Maybe it's ok, but that's a number of additional questions I don't know the answer to.

Comment: Also, H+ and He+ is small and super-fast in the wind, the gaseous stuff could be a gas consisting of much cooler and larger molecules that the membrane behaves differently towards. One thing at a time though, finding something big enough that it doesn't go through some given membrane strikes me as a comparatively easy thing to look for.